# Package installation process struck in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I try to install zip package in my lamp stack in ubuntu 16.04. I'm getting below error after that installation process not moving further. I tried n number of times also I googled I'm not getting any solutions. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
```

[image]

Note: Facing issue not only for this package(php-zip) installation, It's happening for all the package installation.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:
[image]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/808304/install-of-mysql-hangs-on-ubuntu-16-04 may help.

Comment: hey @JonStirling, thanks for your reply. I have tried your solution. But no luck. I have updated my question with screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: You can't run 2 at the same time. You need to kill off the original apt process.